# Getting missing select keyword error when I do have select keyword

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
 (select course_id
 from section
 where semester = 'FALL' AND  year = 2009)
  intersect all 
 (select course_id
 from section
 where semester = 'SPRING' AND  YEAR = 2010);
```

I'm reading Database System Concepts by Henry Korth.I'm trying to do intersection exactly as it is in the book but I'm getting missing select keyword error when I do have select keyword.

Edit: Looks like I'm getting error only when I use 'intersect all' but 'intersect' works fine

Comment: What is "intersect all"? Never heard of it. Did you read that in the book?

Comment: Yes. https://www.amazon.com/Database-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0073523321

Comment: Seriously? Are you SURE? Did you check again in the book? By the way, what SQL dialect does the book claim to be using? There is no `intersect all` in Oracle.

Comment: page 82 of the book.

Comment: OK, I did a quick search and I see there is mention of `intersect all`, meaning keeping duplicates. If you are using Oracle, it does not implement that operator. By the way, be prepared for many differences like that; a lot of things from books and even from the SQL Standard are not implemented in one database product or another, and instead they implement things you won't find in books or in the standard.

Comment: So which SQL should I use? I downloaded Oracle developer to comply with the book.

Comment: Btw this book looks like full in errors.Do you know of any better book?The book was assigned by my school.

Comment: You must read the book assigned by the school anyway. Oracle is perhaps the best choice - just be prepared that some things won't work exactly as the book says. Here's something about `intersect all` if you care (you probably shouldn't). https://sqlpatterns.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/how-to-mimic-minus-all-and-intersect-all-in-oracle/

Comment: ["Buy new: $195.79"](https://www.amazon.com/Database-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0073523321/ref=mt_hardcover?_encoding=UTF8&me=) Amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the `ALL` portion with `INTERSECT` in `Oracle`. `ALL` is used with `UNION`, not with `INTERSECT` or `MINUS`. Try it without... (also the parenthesis are unnecessary, they don't hurt anything, just not needed):

```
select course_id
from section
where semester = 'FALL' AND  year = 2009
intersect
select course_id
from section
where semester = 'SPRING' AND  YEAR = 2010;
```

Apparently `PostgreSQL` supports `ALL` with `INTERSECT`, but `Oracle` does not. I did see where it can be mimiced using the following:

```
with intersect_tbl as
(
    select course_id, row_number(partition by course_id) as rnum
    from section
    where semester = 'FALL' AND  year = 2009
    intersect
    select course_id, row_number(partition by course_id) as rnum
    from section
    where semester = 'SPRING' AND  YEAR = 2010
)
select course_id
from intersect_tbl;
```

Since you mentioned that the book you found your example in is assigned by your school, I would clarify with them if there is a particular DBMS you should be using for your class. As I mentioned `INTERSECT ALL` is available in `PostgreSQL`, so it may be that they intend for you to be using that flavor instead of `Oracle`.

Comment: `rownum` is the name of an automatically-generated column in Oracle; even if this solution doesn't error out, it is better to use a different alias (`rn` is quite common).

Comment: Yah, it shouldn't be a problem, but I changed the alias anyway to `rnum`, which should suffice.

Comment: It will be a problem for a future developer reading the code, not understanding what its purpose is, and being confused by `rownum`. Don't only think about yourself!  :-)

Comment: I mean it shouldn't be a problem for a simple example like this, and I aliased it so there would be no confusion of what it was (not that there should be, and it doesn't even need an alias at all really).